# MicroPython on ESP32 : BLE send/receive string

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, uart, esp32, micropython, thonny

I'm trying to make a communication for ESP32 and my Android tablet. My target is they can send message each other. I use Bluefruit Connect on tablet Android and IDE Thonny for coding. Hera is what I have done

```
from esp_ble_uart import *
import time

nom = 'ESP32_thanh'
UUID_UART = '6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E'
UUID_TX = '6E400003-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E'
UUID_RX = '6E400002-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E'

uart = Bleuart(nom, UUID_UART, UUID_TX, UUID_RX)
uart.close()

def rcp_rx():
    global val_rx
    val_rx = uart.read().decode().strip()
    print('recevoir : ', val_rx)               

uart.irq(handler=rcp_rx)


def env_tx(val_tx):
    uart.write(str(val_tx) + '\n')
    print("envoyer : ", val_tx)

while True:
    env_tx(input())       
    time.sleep_ms(1000)
```

And here is the library I used :

```
import struct
import bluetooth

# Advertising payloads are repeated packets of the following form:
#   1 byte data length (N + 1)
#   1 byte type (see constants below)
#   N bytes type-specific data

_ADV_TYPE_FLAGS = const(0x01)
_ADV_TYPE_NAME = const(0x09)
_ADV_TYPE_UUID16_COMPLETE = const(0x3)
_ADV_TYPE_UUID32_COMPLETE = const(0x5)
_ADV_TYPE_UUID128_COMPLETE = const(0x7)
_ADV_TYPE_UUID16_MORE = const(0x2)
_ADV_TYPE_UUID32_MORE = const(0x4)
_ADV_TYPE_UUID128_MORE = const(0x6)
_ADV_TYPE_APPEARANCE = const(0x19)

_IRQ_CENTRAL_CONNECT = const(1 << 0)
_IRQ_CENTRAL_DISCONNECT = const(1 << 1)
_IRQ_GATTS_WRITE = const(1 << 2)

# org.bluetooth.characteristic.gap.appearance.xml
_ADV_APPEARANCE_GENERIC_COMPUTER = const(128)



# Generate a payload to be passed to gap_advertise(adv_data=...).
def advertising_payload(limited_disc=False, br_edr=False, name=None, services=None, appearance=0):
    payload = bytearray()

    def _append(adv_type, value):
        nonlocal payload
        payload += struct.pack('BB', len(value) + 1, adv_type) + value

    _append(_ADV_TYPE_FLAGS, struct.pack('B', (0x01 if limited_disc else 0x02) + (0x00 if br_edr else 0x04)))

    if name:
        _append(_ADV_TYPE_NAME, name)

    if services:
        for uuid in services:
            b = bytes(uuid)
            if len(b) == 2:
                _append(_ADV_TYPE_UUID16_COMPLETE, b)
            elif len(b) == 4:
                _append(_ADV_TYPE_UUID32_COMPLETE, b)
            elif len(b) == 16:
                _append(_ADV_TYPE_UUID128_COMPLETE, b)

    # See org.bluetooth.characteristic.gap.appearance.xml
    _append(_ADV_TYPE_APPEARANCE, struct.pack('<h', appearance))

    return payload


def decode_field(payload, adv_type):
    i = 0
    result = []
    while i + 1 < len(payload):
        if payload[i + 1] == adv_type:
            result.append(payload[i + 2:i + payload[i] + 1])
        i += 1 + payload[i]
    return result


def decode_name(payload):
    n = decode_field(payload, _ADV_TYPE_NAME)
    return str(n[0], 'utf-8') if n else ''


def decode_services(payload):
    services = []
    for u in decode_field(payload, _ADV_TYPE_UUID16_COMPLETE):
        services.append(bluetooth.UUID(struct.unpack('<h', u)[0]))
    for u in decode_field(payload, _ADV_TYPE_UUID32_COMPLETE):
        services.append(bluetooth.UUID(struct.unpack('<d', u)[0]))
    for u in decode_field(payload, _ADV_TYPE_UUID128_COMPLETE):
        services.append(bluetooth.UUID(u))
    return services

class Bleuart:
    def __init__(self, name, UUID_UART, UUID_TX, UUID_RX, rxbuf=100):

        _UART_UUID = bluetooth.UUID(UUID_UART,)
        _UART_TX = (bluetooth.UUID(UUID_TX), bluetooth.FLAG_NOTIFY,)
        _UART_RX = (bluetooth.UUID(UUID_RX), bluetooth.FLAG_WRITE,)
        _UART_SERVICE = (_UART_UUID, (_UART_TX, _UART_RX,),)


        self._ble = bluetooth.BLE()
        self._ble.active(True)
        self._ble.irq(handler=self._irq)
        ((self._tx_handle, self._rx_handle,),) = self._ble.gatts_register_services((_UART_SERVICE,))
        # Increase the size of the rx buffer and enable append mode.
        self._ble.gatts_set_buffer(self._rx_handle, rxbuf, True)
        self._connections = set()
        self._rx_buffer = bytearray()
        self._handler = None
        # Optionally add services=[_UART_UUID], but this is likely to make the payload too large.
        self._payload = advertising_payload(name=name, appearance=_ADV_APPEARANCE_GENERIC_COMPUTER)
        self._advertise()

    def irq(self, handler):
        self._handler = handler

    def _irq(self, event, data):
        # Track connections so we can send notifications.
        if event == _IRQ_CENTRAL_CONNECT:
            conn_handle, _, _, = data
            self._connections.add(conn_handle)
        elif event == _IRQ_CENTRAL_DISCONNECT:
            conn_handle, _, _, = data
            if conn_handle in self._connections:
                self._connections.remove(conn_handle)
            # Start advertising again to allow a new connection.
            self._advertise()
        elif event == _IRQ_GATTS_WRITE:
            conn_handle, value_handle, = data
            if conn_handle in self._connections and value_handle == self._rx_handle:
                self._rx_buffer += self._ble.gatts_read(self._rx_handle)
                if self._handler:
                    self._handler()

    def any(self):
        return len(self._rx_buffer)

    def read(self, sz=None):
        if not sz:
            sz = len(self._rx_buffer)
        result = self._rx_buffer[0:sz]
        self._rx_buffer = self._rx_buffer[sz:]
        return result

    def write(self, data):
        for conn_handle in self._connections:
            self._ble.gatts_notify(conn_handle, self._tx_handle, data)

    def close(self):
        for conn_handle in self._connections:
            self._ble.gap_disconnect(conn_handle)
        self._connections.clear()

    def _advertise(self, interval_us=500000):
        self._ble.gap_advertise(interval_us, adv_data=self._payload)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import time

    nom = 'esp32-uart-gcworks'
    UUID_UART = '6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E'
    UUID_TX = '6E400003-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E'
    UUID_RX = '6E400002-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E'

    uart = Bleuart(nom, UUID_UART, UUID_TX, UUID_RX)
    uart.close()


    def on_rx():
        print('rx: ', uart.read().decode().strip())

    uart.irq(handler=on_rx)
    nums = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42]
    i = 0

    try:
        while True:
            uart.write(str(nums[i]) + '\n')
            i = (i + 1) % len(nums)
            print(nums[i])
            time.sleep_ms(1000)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

The actually result is I can send message from terminal of Thonny to Android tablet, but the opposite doesn't work.

Have some one have the same problem or anyone can resolve the problem, please reply me on this post. Thank you

Comment: If you have additional info like a log or error message please add it to your question